# How often will two random integers between one and three (boundary inclusive) be the same?

Tags: probability, monty-hall

Assuming the answer is one out of three? And, also, would this be a good distillation of how to understand the "Monty Hall" problem?

Comment: The connection with the Monty Hall problem seems slender.  In that problem, everything depends on the superior knowledge of the host.  You get information from the fact that Monty does not open a certain door.  Hard to connect that up to a truly random draw.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are integers then 1/3, but how does this relate to monty hall at all?

Comment: Thanks Dean.  So I've been making a concerted effort to simplify Monty Hall into the easiest way to understand (for myself at least).  The lightbulb for me was in the fact that it only makes sense to NOT shift to the remaining door, if you actually happened to have guessed correctly initially, but that only happens 33% of the time, so you are always advantaged by switching.  So in attempting to distill that down even further, success rate in shifting to the remaining door would be the same as the probability of two random numbers between one and three NOT being the same, which would be 2/3.